# Set a Pub Sub topic in Micronaut as per environment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, micronaut

I am following this [guide](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-gcp/latest/guide/#producer) to initialise a GCP Pub/Sub publisher.

The coding syntax is as follows:

```
@PubSubClient
public interface PubSubService {

    @Topic("topic-a")
    void send(final A a);

    @Topic("topic-b")
    void send(final B b);

}
```

I want to set this topic value based on the environment, as I will have a different topic for QA/DEV (say `topic-a-qa` and `topic-b-qa`).
Is there any way for me to set this String value in the `@Topic` annotation via or based on environment properties?

I do not have an option of have a different Project under the GCP account, also creating a different class for QA overriding this one is not so graceful when maintaining environments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [placeholders](https://docs.micronaut.io/2.5.13/guide/index.html#valueAnnotation) inside Micronaut's annotations.

```java
@PubSubClient
public interface PubSubService {

    @Topic("${topic.a.name:topic-a}")
    void send(final A a);

    @Topic("${topic.b.name:topic-b}")
    void send(final B b);

}
```

The expression `${topic.a.name:topic-a}` instructs Micronaut to search for the value in the configuration under the `topic.a.name` key, and fall back to the value `topic-a` if the configuration key is not found. Then you can configure different topic names using e.g. `application-qa.yml` configuration file:

<sub>*src/main/resources/application-qa.yml*</sub>

```yaml
topic:
  a:
    name: topic-a-qa
  b:
    name: topic-b-qa
```

Lastly, just make sure that when you run the application in the QA environment you [set a proper active environment](https://docs.micronaut.io/2.5.13/guide/index.html#environments), e.g.

```
$ java -Dmicronaut.environments=qa -jar myapp.jar
```

Comment: Kudos for the perfect answer!!! I was unsure about how or whether we can use application properties within the annotation values.